# PHP requests need body/form content to be sent with quotations

Tags: php, http, request, http-post

I need to send the body with quotation for the http post request to work. The correct body content should look like this:

```
{"pnr" : "123", "orgnr" : "456"}
```

**Question:** How can I use below code as a base and get above body as outcome?

I am using this document as reference: https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/blob/master/docs/usage.md

---

**Results of attempts (summary):**

Attempt-1:

```
"data": "{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}"
```

Attempt-2:

```
"data": "{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}"
```

Attempt-3:

```
"form": {"{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}": ""
```

**Attempt 1 - Encode json string, sending body inside [$data].**

```
require_once '../../../../packages/Requests/library/Requests.php';
Requests::register_autoloader();

$url      = 'http://httpbin.org/post';

$data = '{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}';

$headers = array(
    'Accept-Encoding'  => 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept'           => 'application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*',
    'Content-Type'     => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
);

$response_1 = Requests::post($url, $headers, json_encode($data));

var_dump($response_1->body);
```

Attempt 1 - Result:

```
string(567) "{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "\"{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}\"", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "41", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Referer": "http://httpbin.org/post", 
    "User-Agent": "php-requests/1.7"
  }, 
  "json": "{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}", 
  "origin": "82.117.105.239, 8"...
```

---

**Attempt 2 - Send json string without encode, sending body inside [$data].**

```
require_once '../../../../packages/Requests/library/Requests.php';
Requests::register_autoloader();

$url      = 'http://httpbin.org/post';

$data = '{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}';

$headers = array(
    'Accept-Encoding'  => 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept'           => 'application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*',
    'Content-Type'     => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
);

$response_2 = Requests::post($url, $headers, $data);

var_dump($response_2->body);
```

Attempt 2 - Result:

```
string(526) "{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "39", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Referer": "http://httpbin.org/post", 
    "User-Agent": "php-requests/1.7"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "82.117.105.239, 82.117.105.239", 
  "url": "https://httpbi"...
```

---

**Attempt 3 - Send json string without encode, sending body inside of [form].**

```
require_once '../../../../packages/Requests/library/Requests.php';
Requests::register_autoloader();

$url      = 'http://httpbin.org/post';

$data = '{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}';

$headers = array(
    'Accept-Encoding'  => 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept'           => 'application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*',
    'Content-Type'     => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
);

$response_2 = Requests::post($url, array(), $data);

var_dump($response_3->body);
```

Attempt 3 - Result:

```
string(497) "{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "{personal_number: 123, org_number: 456}": ""
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip", 
    "Content-Length": "39", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Referer": "http://httpbin.org/post", 
    "User-Agent": "php-requests/1.7"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "82.117.105.239, 82.117.105.239", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: Why should quoting integers in the JSON payload be the "correct" serialization?

Comment: @mario It it is a valid queston. I created a http request soution in the programming language "R". When that was working I observed the sent data where the paload has quoting.It might of course be the case this is not needed using PHP requests package.

Comment: Whether it's needed depends on the receiving end. (With quoted numericals being the odd case). The used HTTP client library wouldn't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array 
then set key and its value 
finally, it should be wrapped in json_encode.

```
$data = Array();
$data["personal_number"] = "123";
$data["org_number"] = "456";

$response_2 = Requests::post($url, $headers, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: I now get a "200 OK" as answer. What I am not clear about is that both you and the above mentioned documentation, removes the [$headers] when you add [array()]. Is it not possible to keep the [$headers] if one would use [array()] ? If you could please update your answer explaining about using the combination [$array()] and [$headers], I will go ahead and accept the answer.

Comment: I edited the answer, I forgot to change the array to header haha sorry

Comment: Changing the [$array] to [$headers] still gives a [200 ok], even though the quotations of the body are not wrapped as previously requested. I will go ahead and accept the answer anyhow since I now have a base of continuing testing.